# Complex restructuring of R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

as I have a dataframe like this:

```
participant v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6
 1          4  2     9  7  2
 2             6  8        1
 3                5  4     5
 4          1  1     2  3
```

Every two consecutive variables (v1 and v2, v3 and v4, v5 and v6) belong to each other (this is what I call "count" later).

I desperatly search a way to get the following:

```
participant count  v(odd numbers) v(even numbers)
 1           1      4              2 
             2                     9
             3      7              2
 2           1                     6
             2      8
             3                     1
 3           1
             2      5              4
             3                     5
 4           1      1              1
             2                     2
             3      3
```

As this is my first question on stackoverflow ever, I hope you understand my request. I searched a lot for similar problems (and solutions to them) but found nothing. I would very much appreciate your support.

Comment: what do you mean by 'belong to each other'? what have you tried so far? can you share the code? you can use `dput()` on your data frame to make this example easier to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `melt`

```
 library(data.table)
 melt(setDT(d1), measure = list(paste0("v", seq(1, 6, by= 2)),
          paste0("v", seq(2,6, by = 2))))[order(participant)]
#    participant variable value1 value2
# 1:           1        1      4      2
# 2:           1        2     NA      9
# 3:           1        3      7      2
# 4:           2        1     NA      6
# 5:           2        2      8     NA
# 6:           2        3     NA      1
# 7:           3        1     NA     NA
# 8:           3        2      5      4
# 9:           3        3     NA      5
#10:           4        1      1      1
#11:           4        2     NA      2
#12:           4        3      3     NA
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @akrun, for your quick reply. I assumed that `melt` would be the solution, but had no idea about that additionally arguments you used. Looks exactly like what I asked for. Unfortunately when I apply this to my data frame, I get an error: `Unknown 'measure.var' type list, must be character or integer vector"`. Here's my line: `melt(setDT(sub.cr), measure = list(paste0("valence", seq(1, 400, by= 2)), paste0("arousal", seq(2,400, by = 2))))[order(lfdn)]`. What is my mistake?

Comment: @scylyne  Can you update your post with the dput of a small dataset that shows the error